# Functions in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I need to call a function when button is clicked it is not working in jsp.
I used html and jsp in the following code. when button is clicked it should display the lines present in the function.

```
          <%! 
        public int displaydata(JspWriter out) throws Exception
            {
       out.print("test");
       return 0;
                }
               %>
       <html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
 body  {

background-color: #cccccc;
   }
  tab{ padding-left: 4em; }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <form>
    <title>Businesscard Management</title>
     </head>
        <body>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
       <h2>   Search : <input type="text" class="textbox" size="75"     autofocus="true" name="searchinput"/>
      <input type="submit" value="find" onclick="displaydata(out)"/>
       </h2>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The key here is understanding the difference between server-side code and client-side code. By the time the page arrives in the user's browser, all server-side code has already been executed, so you can't call a server-side function from a client-side event like a click. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may want to consider using ajax to communicate with the server when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that

The `onclick` event handler captures a click event from the users mouse button on the element to which the onclick attribute is applied This action usually
results in a call to a `script method` such as a `JavaScript` function, like
this:

```
onclick="myFunction();"
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var field1 = document.getElementById('textfield').value;  
     
    alert(field1);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="75" autofocus="true" name="searchinput" id="textfield"/>
<input type="submit" value="find" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

So I suggest that you use javascript code

If you want to test scriplets(<% ... %>) in your page

you should learn the basic concepts of Java web development. Good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm)

Comment: using jsp functions is possible or not .Explain if not.

Comment: I am learning JSP. I can't find the answer of it plese help me.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm